# Array of Observable is empty when loading the page but has content later on?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable, json-server

I'm trying to implement ngx-infinite-scroll. I want to take the first 5 posts out of my "posts" array and put them into "shownPosts" array at the start and then when the user keeps scrolling down I want it to add another 5 but I ran into a problem where my "posts" array is empty while the side is still loading (ngOnInit).

If I check the array with another function (checkPosts) later it's got all of the Posts. Why is that?

Console logs when website loads:

```
In constructor, this.posts.length: 0
In ngOnInit, this.posts.length: 0
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')       core.mjs:6485 
    at HotComponent.ngOnInit (hot.component.ts:37:70)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2542:1)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2511:1)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2462:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9499:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9508:1)
```

Console log after I run "checkPosts()" through a button once the site has loaded:

```
In checkPosts, this.posts.length: 32
In checkPosts, this.posts[0].title: This is the first posts title.
```

**hot.component.ts:**

```
import ...

@Component({
...
})

export class HotComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Post[] = [];
  shownPosts: Post[] = [];
  normalDrawerShown: boolean = true;
  subscription!: Subscription;
...

constructor(private postService: PostService, private uiService: UiService) {
  this.subscription = this.uiService
  .onToggleNormalDrawer()
  .subscribe((value) => (this.normalDrawerShown = value));

  console.log("In constructor, this.posts.length: "+ this.posts.length);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => (this.posts = posts));

  console.log("In ngOnInit, this.posts.length: "+ this.posts.length);
  console.log("In ngOnInit, this.posts[0].title: " + this.posts[0].title);
}

checkPosts():void{
  console.log("In checkPosts, this.posts.length: "+ this.posts.length);
  console.log("In checkPosts, this.posts[0].title: " + this.posts[0].title);
}
...
}
```

**Post.ts:**

```
export interface Post {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  fileName: string;
  url: string;
  section: string;
  postTime: string;
  upvotes: number;
  downvotes: number;
  comments: number;
}
```

**post.service.ts:**

```
getPosts():Observable<Post[]> {
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how async processes work. You need to deal with the fact that you don't have the value to start with - provide a default value, guard against early access, use the async pipe, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http request to backend api take time.

*this line of code:*

```
this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => (this.posts = posts));
```

...means that when observable *created here:*

```
this.http.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl);
```

...emits value (therefore when http request return some value) then take that value and assign it to `this.posts`. And since http requests take some time, that value is not showed when you try to console.log it right after subscription.